# как воспроизвести цикл заданное количество раз в python?

Tags: python

```
import random
a = int(input("Сколько раз выполнять поиск?"))

gg = True

while gg:
    hf = random.randrange (0, 10, 1)
    print (hf)
```

Comment: while gg заменить на for _ in range(a)

Comment: Или gg+=1; if gg==4:break

Answer (score 5):

Используйте цикл `for`

```
for ... in range(a):
    print(...)
```

Вместо `...` используйте ваши переменные. Также советую почитать про цикл `for`.